# Hibernate Proxy getter returning null values

Tags: hibernate, lazy-evaluation, many-to-one

I'm working on a existing source where all @XXXToOne associations are eagerly fetched (default), due to performance issues of eager fetching ,i managed to set those associations to LAZY. but i'm facing a weird problem (never got this before), calling the getter on a @ManyToOne annotated field returns empty object with enmpty values.
The session is not closed ( spring transaction and jpa log debug on ), 
the case is not systematic , some @ManyToOne are correctly loaded.
to investigate i took all the entity model project code and put it on a new spring boot jpa project with the same hibernate/jpa version (4.3.1 / 2.1) and created a service that fetches the same entity, and the lazy loading of the association by calling the getter works correctly , the same code , on the same database,  (may be not the same libs ) , the setter/getter methods are marked final, but this works on the stand alone spring boot project , removing the modifier on the originan entity does not resolve the problem.
thank you for your Help.

```
       @Entity
       @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "BL_DELETE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "char")
       @DiscriminatorValue("0")
       @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
       @SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE OM_STEP SET BL_DELETE=1, TS_DELETE=SYSDATE WHERE ID_STEP=? and VERSION=?")
       @Table(name = "OM_STEP")
       public class OmStepEntity implements Serializable {
          @Id
          @Column(name = "ID_STEP")
          @SequenceGenerator(name = "STEP_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_STEP", allocationSize = 1)
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STEP_ID_GENERATOR")
          private Long stepId;

        // primitives fields 
         .....
        //associations

         @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
          @JoinColumn(name = "ID_STEP_MODEL")
          private OrStepModelEntity stepModel;

          @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
          @JoinColumn(name = "ID_WORK")
          private OmWorkEntity work;

         public final void setStepModel(final OrStepModelEntity stepModel) {
           this.stepModel= stepModel;
         }
         public final OrStepModelEntity getStepModel() {
           return stepModel;
         }
         public final OmWorkEntity  getWork() {
           return work;
         }
         public final void setWork(final OmWorkEntity work) {
           this.work= work;
         }


        }
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "OR_STEP_MODEL")
     public class OrStepModelEntity implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID_STEP_MODEL")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_STEP_MODEL_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_STEP_MODEL", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  "ID_STEP_MODEL_GENERATOR")
        private Long stepModelId;  

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stepModel")
        private List < OmStepEntity > stepList;
         public List < OmStepEntity > getStepList() {
           return stepList;
         }
       public void setStepList(final List < OmStepEntity > stepList) {
         this.stepList= stepList;
       }

     }
     @Entity
     @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "BL_DELETE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "char")
     @DiscriminatorValue("0")
     @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
     @SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE OM_WORK SET BL_DELETE=1, TS_DELETE=SYSDATE WHERE ID_WORK=? and VERSION=?")
     @Table(name = "OM_WORK")
     public class OmWorkEntity implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID_WORK")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_WORK_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_WORK", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_WORK_GENERATOR")
        private Long workId;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_WORK_MODEL")
        private OrWorkModelEntity workModel;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "work")
        private List < OmStepEntity > stepList;

     public final OrWorkModelEntity getWorkModel() {
        return workModel;
      }

     public final void setWorkModel(final OrWorkModelEntity workModel) {
        this.workModel= workModel;
      }
     public final List < OmStepEntity > getStepList() {
        return stepList;
      }

     public final void setStepList(final List < OmStepEntity > stepList) {
        this.stepList= stepList;
     }
    }

public class StepPersistenceImpl implements IStepPersistence {
 ....
 public final OmStepVo rechercherEtapeParId(final Long stepId) {
    final OmStepEntity result= getEntityManager().find(OmStepEntity.class, stepId);
    return OmStepEntityUtils.toValueObject(result);

  }
}
```

the OmStepEntityUtils.toValueObject creates a Value Object ( a DTO) from the entity, inside when calling the getStepModel() i can see an sql query triggered for the stepModel entity , but calling the getWork() does not force the lazy association to initialize and no sql query is triggered
i added ((HibernateProxy) entite).getHibernateLazyInitializer().isUninitialized() in the copy utility and it returns true. i can't see why hibernate ignores the association.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you GileadKenzo, i edited the Post.

Comment: You are Welcome... :)

Comment: Does calling entityManager.refresh() on the OrmStepEntity before calling getWork() cause getWork() to work as desired?  I have an entity whose getter of a @OneToMany field returns null until I call this refresh method on it.